# How to execute @BeforeMethod of another class in case of multiple testng classes

Tags: java, annotations, testng

Problem Statement : I have got multiple testng classes which have @BeforeMethod & @Test methods & some tests are invoked via another test method. The BeforeMethod methods in such a case does not get executed.

For e.g.

```
public class A {

    @BeforeMethod
    public void preCheck(){
         System.out.println("Pre-Check A");
    }

    @Test
    public void check(){
         System.out.println("Check A");
         B objB = new B();
         objB.check();
    }
}

public class B {

    @BeforeMethod
    public void preCheck(){
        System.out.println("Pre-Check B");
    }

    @Test
    public void check(){
        System.out.println("Check B");
    }
}
```

When I execute class A as Testng class, I get the following output

```
Pre-Check A
Check A
Check B
```

Whereas desired output is

```
Pre-Check A
Check A
Pre-Check B
Check B
```

How can I achieve the same ?

Comment: You should create an  object hierachie.

Comment: Try to invoke using the testng.xml file

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are having this issue is because unit test frameworks aren't meant to work that way. This isn't really a best practice when it comes to unit testing since you are testing multiple units at once. You need to isolate the unit in which you are trying to test. In that test, set up all of your pre conditions in your method annotated with @BeforeMethod.

If you must have them in one test because they are so closely coupled then create one unit test that instantiates both and test them that way in one test. A better approach would be to mock B in your A test so that you can specify what outputs B will produce and test the functionality of A in that case.

If you give a more specific example of what you are trying to test then I can give you some code on how to test it.

Comment: Hi @Josh, thanks for your inputs. I am creating a test-framework for end-to-end intergration use-cases which may deal with different components, for e.g. web-service api testing, web-driver UI testing, sql call to a database etc, which may or may not be a single test. My plan is to build dedicated libraries for similar components & make them generic as well as inter-operable which could be used by other teams in my org as well.

Comment: For e.g an use-case where I perform some actions on UI & verify them using a rest based web-service call. So my test-script will call methods from classes like -> MasterTests.java -> UITests.java -> WebServiceTests.java.
Now I need beforemethods for each of these classes so that it caters to wide range of use-cases without depending upon a specific point of entry becuase for e.g some other team may only need to call WebServiceTests.java & therefore that beforemethod should pre-configure the test accordingly.
If you could suggest some better approaches for achieving this !!! Thanks in advance